# I need the Broadcom ethernet Driver installer for Dell inspiron 1521 ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, drivers, broadcom

Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4401-B0 100Base-TX [14e4:170c] (rev 02)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your wireless device uses the proprietary Broadcom STA driver. Installing this driver remarkably blacklists the ethernet driver b44 and its dependency ssb. When b44 and ssb load, they usually bring along b43, the wrong and conflicting driver for your wireless. That's why the blacklist.

Please load the driver for the ethernet:

```
sudo modprobe b44
```

If the ethernet and wireless both work as expected, I will further edit this answer to propose a solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is something give in the [official site](https://www.broadcom.com/support/ethernet_nic/4401.php). Do not know if this will be helpful.